# A while back - A Unix distribution with installation media that could boot on several platforms?

Tags: system-installation, iso, multiboot

Quite a while I saw a distribution of a *nix operating system where the installation media (CD? DVD?) contained binaries for several hardware platforms, and could boot and install directly on *several* of these.  My best bet is that this was either OpenBSD or NetBSD but I cannot remember when or where I saw this.

I would like to have a closer look at the boot code making this possible.

My question is, what was it I saw back then?

Comment: Definitely, its OpenBSD 2.1 - https://www.openbsd.org/21.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of a couple of systems whose installation CDs can be booted on multiple platforms.

The first is OpenBSD, as you seem to remember. [OpenBSD 2.1](https://www.openbsd.org/21.html)'s first CD can boot on i386, ARC and SPARC; [OpenBSD 3.0](https://www.openbsd.org/30.html)'s first CD can boot on i386 and Alpha; and so it goes. (Some CDs include additional architectures with more complex booting requirements, *e.g.* over the network or using other tools to copy files.) The current release, [OpenBSD 6.0](https://www.openbsd.org/60.html), supports i386, Alpha and HPPA off its first CD, but only i386 can boot from the CD; Alpha needs a floppy and HPPA a network boot.

The second is Debian, which has had a variety of multi-architecture CDs. The current release, [Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.6.0/multi-arch/iso-cd/), can boot on i386 and amd64. Older releases supported a variety of architectures from single CDs; for example, [Debian 4](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/4.0_r0/multi-arch/iso-cd/) had one CD for i386, amd64 and PowerPC, and another for Alpha, HPPA and Itanium.

Comment: I didn't know that, I was always under the impression it's just i386 and amd64 which on which those CD's could run.